# Wait for Service Api call to complete in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am trying my first Angular 8 Crud Web app and wrote a page to list some company names from WebApi

My Service is correctly getting data and Iam able to print it on console

```
//Service.ts
export class CompanyService {
  allCompanys: Company[]
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  // Returns all the companys
  GetAll(): Company[] {

    this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company').subscribe(result => {
      this.allCompanys = result;

      //Shows data Sucessfully from Server :Working fine
      console.log(this.allCompanys);

    }, error => console.error(error));

    return this.allCompanys;
  }
```

But in my component I try to get the data at the starting of page by calling the service and assign it to local varaible it is giving undefined

```
     ///Component.ts

      export class CompanyListComponent implements OnInit {
      Companylist: Company[] 
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private companyService: CompanyService) {  }
        ngOnInit() {

          this.Companylist = this.companyService.GetAll();  
          //This is executing before the service call is returning and returning Undefined
          console.log("At Component " + this.Companylist)

        }
```

My html look likes below and table not showing

```
  //html

      <tr *ngFor="let company of Companylist">
      <td>{{company.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{company.Phone}}</td>
      <td>{{company.Email}}</td>
      <td>{{company.Address}}</td>
       < /tr>
```

I tried Observables also but not working.I need the variable to bind after the api is called.Can somebody advice what I am doing wrong

I had already checked the similar cases in SO and cant find something similar(may be not understanding to me)

Comment: When you assign your variable like that, it doesn't wait for the end of the asynchronous request,  Your GetAll() method should return an observable and subscribe to it inside your component then assign your local variable when observable is complete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http request is done as asynchronous operation so will start requesting but the execution of `getAll` asynchronous so will immediately get to the return statement and return what every `allCompanys` has.

to solve this you need to update GetAll to return an observable

```
GetAll(): Observable<Company[]> {
   return  this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company')
}
```

at the component you subscribe to the getAll

```
this.companyService.GetAll().subscribe( result=> this.Companylist = result );
```

and we can simplify the above code with **async** pipe

```
Companylist$ : Observable<Company[]>;

ngOnInit(){

Companylist$ = this.companyService.GetAll();

}
```

*template*

```
<tr *ngFor="let company of Companylist$ | async">
...
</tr>
```

> async pipe subscribes to the observable and returns the latest value it has emitted.

another way is to use `async/await`, so we need to update `GetAll` to return a promise and it is very easy to convert observable to promise with **toPromise** method

```
GetAll(): Promise<Company[]> {
   return  this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company')
          .toPromise(); // 
}
```

*componnet*

```
async ngOnInit() {

  this.Companylist = await this.companyService.GetAll();  
   ...
}
```

read more about it here  [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest code for you to understand**

*In your component ts:*

```
ngOnInit() {
    // callback gets executed when your service gets the response in the API call
    const callback = function(companyList: Company[]) {
      this.Companylist = companyList;
    }
    this.companyService.GetAll(callback);
    console.log("At Component " + this.Companylist)
}
```

*In your service ts:*

```
GetAll(callback?: Function) {

    this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company').subscribe(result => {
      this.allCompanys = result;

      //Shows data Sucessfully from Server :Working fine
      console.log(this.allCompanys);
      if(callback) {
        callback(this.allCompanys);
      }

    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are returning `this.allCompanys` before the async call `this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company')` gets resolved.

---

##### Option 1:

1. Return an `Observable Company[]` like:

```
return this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company')
```

2. Catch it in your view with an [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#unwrapping-data-from-an-observable) like:

```
allCompanys | async
```

---

##### Option 2:

1. Remove the typed `return Company[]` and make `GetAll()` return `void`.
2. Keep `this.allCompanys = result` in the subscription, so the field is resolved when the call returns.
3. Do something when it gets resolved, like

```
if (this.allCompanys) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the service, `this.allCompanys` is returned synchronously even before you get the response. So it returns `Undefined`. But when the response comes, the component no longer checks the update.

So You need to update the value asynchronously.

```
GetAll(): Company[] {
    return this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('https://localhost:565656/api/company');
}
```

in component

```
this.companyService.GetAll().subScribe((res) => {
    this.Companylist = res;
}, error => console.error(error)
)
```