# How to display modal after a delay in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

In My `angular` application, when the user clicks on the confirmation button in the main modal I am invoking API methods, and based on success or failure response I have to display the success or failure modal dialog box.

But at present, success or failure modal dialog box getting displayed as soon as the user clicks on the confirmation button and not waiting for API methods response as I am using data-target and toggle in my HTML.

In google, could see the below answer for javascript but not sure how to achieve the same in Typescript.

I tried `*ngIf="isSuccess"` or `*ngIf="isFailed"` but modal dialog not getting displayed.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
}, 2000);
```

Can someone help me to achieve this behavior in Typescript?

Comment: please add your API call and more detail

Comment: if you use rxjs, you can call the modal after the response has resolved. Using a timeout function isnt recommended, since you never know how long it will take

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59171532/wait-for-service-api-call-to-complete-in-angular-8

Answer (score 1):

Use RxJS Observable or Promise to handle this situation.
So let's assume you have apiCall which will resolve into true or false.
Your code will be something like this:

```
apiCall().subscribe(
  (result) => {
    if(result){
      // open dialog for success
    }else {
      // open dialog for fail
    }
  }
)
```